# Timeout powershell command

Tags: powershell, timeout, powershell-4.0

I'm using ODP.net with Powershell to execute query on my Oracle Database.

I want to time-out the execution of my query. This is my code :

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")
$OracleConnexion = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection('User Id=test;Password="test";Data Source=10.0.0.0/TEST')

$FluxSiebel = "SELECT * FROM BLABLA"

Try { 

    $OracleConnexion.Open()

}Catch { 

    Write-Output "Connection KO"
    $OracleConnexion
    Exit 2
}


$Query=$OracleConnexion.CreateCommand()
$Query.CommandText=$FluxSiebel

$TimeTaken=  (Measure-Command  {

    $ExecuteQuery=$Query.ExecuteReader()

}).TotalMilliseconds | Out-String
```

I want to add a timeout of 1minutes on this section of my code : `$ExecuteQuery=$Query.ExecuteReader()`

How can I do this? I can't find any cmdlet doing this...

Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51173_01/win.122/e17732/OracleCommandClass.htm#DAFBGECA ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the CommandTimeout on the Command object returned from CreateCommand()

Example

```
$cmd=$OracleConnexion.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText=$FluxSiebel
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 60; # 1 minute (60 seconds)
```